# ¿Cómo pasar selector multiple por una clase y posteriormente en SQL query?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un selector múltiple que deseo pasar por una clase de seguridad, ver si el valor de POST es igual `= '0'`, si no es así pasarlo a una variable para posteriormente ponerlo en una query de SQL.

Estos son los problemas a los que me enfrento:

1. [SOLUCIONADO] Al pasar un array por la clase me da este error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test_input()`
2. [SOLUCIONADO] No sé cómo ver si el unico valor seleccionado es igual a 0
3. No sé cómo pasar el array a una variable
4. No sé como incluir la variable en una query de SQL con varios valores a un `WHERE IN`

Éste es mi código:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="selector[]" multiple>
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>';


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $testado = $_POST["selector"];

    if ( $testado == '0') {
        echo 'El resultado seleccionado es 0';
    } else {
        foreach ($_POST["selector"] as $selector) {
            // ESTO FUNCCIONA
            echo $selectorMULTIPLE = "OR selector ='". $selector . "' ";
        }
    echo '<hr>'. $EnviarDB = '"'. $selectorMULTIPLE .'",';
    }

   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
```

Comment: <form method="post" action="">
 <select name="selector[]" multiple>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
 </select>
 <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

Comment: La función `test_input` está dentro del `if`. Sácala de ahí y eso debería solucionar tu primer problema.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, que me podrias aconsejar sobre los problemas 2, 3 y 4 ?

Comment: Para comprobar si hay un único valor seleccionado y éste es 0, ¿no lo puedes hacer con `len($testeado) === 1 && $testeado[0] === '0')`?

Comment: Gustavo, me da error: Call to undefined function len()

Comment: Perdón, es `sizeof`. `len` es de Python.

Comment: Gracias Gustavo, eso me ha solucionado el segundo problema..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. No sé cómo ver si el unico valor seleccionado es igual a 0

Este punto lo puedes solucionar con la siguiente condición:

```
if (sizeof($testeado) === 1 && $testeado[0] === '0') { ... }
```

> 3. No sé cómo pasar el array a una variable

El array **ya es una variable**. Pasarla a otra es redundante.

> 4. No sé como incluir la variable en una query de SQL con varios valores a un `WHERE IN`

Iterando `$testeado` y agregando cada elemento a la consulta:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE campo IN (";

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($testado); $i++) {
  if ($i === sizeof($testado) - 1) {
    $suffix = "";
  } else {
    $suffix = ", ";
  }
  $sql .= "{$testado[$i]}{$suffix}";
}
$sql .= ");";
```

En este punto tendrás la consulta completa, solo te resta ejecutarla via PDO o mysqli.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo estoy intentando.

Comment: Me da error en punto 1. Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in